# How to manage a queue for individual users in ASP.NET Core 6 with global access

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, error-handling, message-queue

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API solution with 4 layers each in its own project in the solution:

- REST API layer handling the REST request (has access to httpcontext)
- Business Logic Layer
- AWS Layer
- Class Library (trying to manage a global message queue per user here).

I am trying to implement a message queue for individual session (per user) so that one user's errors or warnings are not interfered by another's. I want to implement the Message Manager on the Class Library Project (the lowest in the dependency tree) so that it may be used by any other project in the solution. However, making a global static class on the class library project will not allow an instance of Message Manager per user.

Any suggestions on the best way to design this?

I tried injecting the HttpContextAccessor in the (non-static) MessageManager from a SetupController but then I had to store it in a static field which I thought would mean any concurrent users will overwrite the httpcontextaccessor field since its a static field in a non-static class.

I expect to AddMessages, ClearMessages, CheckIfMessageExist globally from any project and any class/function on my MessageManager but still keep it specific to each API Context Session (user).